# Codeigniter pagination not working when using get_where instead of get

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, pagination

I am working on a *Register and Login* application with CodeIgniter 3 and Twitter Bootstrap.

The application has 2 tables: *users* and *customers*. Once logged in the *users* can add their *customers*.

The Customers are displayed in a *paginated table*, like the image bellow shows:

[image]

It has been easy for me to show *all* the customers in the database, regardless of the user that has added them:

*The controller*

```
class Home extends CI_Controller { 
   public function index() {
        $this->load->model('Customer');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config = [
            'base_url' => base_url("/home/"),
            'page_query_string' => TRUE,
            'query_string_segment' => 'page',
            'display_pages' => TRUE,
            'use_page_numbers' => TRUE,
            'per_page' => 10,
            'total_rows' =>    $this->Customer->get_num_rows(),
            'uri_segment' => 3,
            'first_link' => '&laquo;',
            'first_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
            'first_tag_close' => '</li>',
            'last_link' => '&raquo;',
            'last_tag_open' =>  '<li>',
            'last_tag_close' => '</li>',
            'full_tag_open' =>    '<ul class="pagination">',
            'full_tag_close' =>    '</ul>',
            'next_link' =>    '&rsaquo;',
            'next_tag_open' =>    '<li>',
            'next_tag_close' =>    '</li>',
            'prev_link' => '&lsaquo;',
            'prev_tag_open' =>    '<li>',
            'prev_tag_close' =>    '</li>',
            'num_tag_open' =>    '<li>',
            'num_tag_close' =>    '</li>',
            'cur_tag_open' =>    '<li class="active"><a>',
            'cur_tag_close' =>    '</a></li>'
        ];
        if (!isset($_GET[$config['query_string_segment']]) || $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] < 1) {
            $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] = 1;
        }
        $uid = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $limit = $config['per_page'];
        $offset = ($this->input->get($config['query_string_segment']) - 1) * $limit;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $customers = $this->Customer->getCustomers($limit, $offset);
        if ($this->agent->is_mobile()) {
            $this->load->view('mobile/home', ['records'=>$customers]);
        } else {
            $this->load->view('home', ['records'=>$customers]);
        }
    }
}
```

*The model*

```
class Customer extends CI_Model {    
   public function getCustomers($limit, $offset) {
    $query = $this->db->get('customers', $limit, $offset);
    return $query->result();
   }
}
```

But I need to be able to show, to each signed in user, his customers *only*. So, in the *controller*, I have:

1. added the signed in user id `$uid = $this->session->userdata('user_id');`
2. replaced `$customers = $this->Customer->getCustomers($limit, $offset);` with `$customers = $this->Customer->getCustomers($uid, $limit, $offset);`

In the model I have changed the `getCustomers()` method to:

```
public function getCustomers($uid, $limit, $offset) {
     $query = $this->db->get_where('customers', ['uid' => $uid], $limit, $offset);
    return $query->result();
}
```

In this case, the pagination shows more items then it should: there is only one page but there is a link to page 2, witch has no items.

[image]

Where is my mistake?

Comment: stop showing personal data like name, email, phone in your images! or post that these are test data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting the same number of results as you are when getting ALL the customers. So the pagination class still thinks you have the same number of entries.
i.e

```
'total_rows' =>    $this->Customer->get_num_rows(),
```

But when using get_where you are reducing that count. So you'll need to change up how you calculate 'total_rows' to suit.